# Using OBIEE with External Data

Tags: oracle12c, obiee, external-data-access

My organization is looking to replace an access database with OBIEE for a budget forecast. The issue we have is the user wants to manually input values against our data to produce the forecast. This is easily done with forms in Access however, I'm struggling to find a way in OBIEE. So the question is how do we allow the user to input data to our data warehouse and use it in OBIEE analytics without affecting our tables?

We have tried enabling "write back" to the database in our dev environment. We've also discussed using an excel file as an external data source but, the user would prefer not to have to gather all of the data into an .XLS or .CSV

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that is not an easy feature in OBIEE 12, I think (though I haven't research this) that new features to upload your own data (although probably in the form of a csv, xml, json or excel file) have been added to the current version of OBIEE (OBIEE as a product has been discontinued by Oracle, the new versions are called OAC (cloud) or OAS (your own server)).

With OBIEE12, if write back isn't possible, you'll have to find a solution outside OBIEE, some tool to interact with the database like APEX (for Oracle Databases) or whatever you choose. You can add an URL in your report or in the upper menu to link to the form allowing to add the data you choose, but I wouldn't perform data modification inside OBIEE.

Comment: Ana said it all...
OBIEE writeback is mainly for single value input or very simple things. If your needs are for users to be able to enter and modify data for the forecast, you maybe wants to explore using an APEX app for that. The APEX app can be embedded in the OBIEE dashboard pages, making it look like a single app.
OBIEE 12c introduced VA (now called DV) where users can upload and update datasets via Excel files or a number of others. The feature has been extended in Oracle Analytics Server (the new name of OBIEE: same product, different name) and OAC (cloud).